# What are the advantages of using a morpheme-based dictionary in a speech recognition system?

Tags: morphology, dictionary, morphemes, lemmas

What are the advantages of using a morphologically-based  / lemma-based dictionary in a speech recognition system as opposed to a dictionary of 'Orthography' + 'transcription' or other types (which I am currently unaware of... enlighten me please!)?

Comment: This sounds a bit like homework ;) In any case, you might want to point out what motivates your question, and what you already know - Surely you can make an educated guess as to the advantages of one solution over another. Doing this will raise the chances of getting a useful answer.

Comment: My guess is that it allows for linguistic creativity. If you're parsing morphemes you may be more readily able to determine the meaning of novel words. Eg: X (adj)->Xness/+ noun. ; cool(adj)+ness = coolness(noun)

Comment: Sorry, the question is a little vague... I am new to this field, and my current uni doesn't have any courses in this area (although I am in the linguistics dept...). I suppose I am wondering which kind of dictionary is most useful in helping figure out how something is pronounced in English. e.g. a dictionary in this format (morphologically-based):
LEMMA: HELP 
HELPS

Comment: HELPS    HH EH1 L P S
HELPED    HH EH1 L P T
HELPING    HH EH1 L - P IH0 NG
...
OR 
as Orthography + transcription
HELP   HH EH1 L P
HELPABLE   HH EH1 L - P AH0 - B AH0 L
HELPDESK    HH ..
...
HELPS ...